# Check if a hash is the first element after first slash in href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu with links that may look like one of the following:

```
mywebsite.com/#find
mywebsite.com/about-us/#team
mywebsite.com/#social
mywebsite.com/services/#something
```

I want to do something **only** to the first and third links (the ones that don't have a subdirectory in the url path). How do I check if a # hash is the first element after the first slash in the link?

```
$('#menu a').click(function() {
    
  var target = this.href;

  // check if "/#" is the first thing after the domain name
 
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class that parse URLs can help you. [`URL.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) property contain path of url (string after domain)

```
$('#menu a').click(function(e) {
  if (new URL(this.href).pathname == "/"){
    // Do something
  }
});
```

More accurate mode is

```
$('#menu a').click(function(e) {
  let url = new URL(this.href)
  if (url.pathname == "/" && url.hash != ''){
    // Do something
  }
});
```

```js
$('#menu a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (new URL(this.href).pathname == "/")
    console.log("true");
});
```

```css
a {display: block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <a href="http://mywebsite.com/#find">mywebsite.com/#find</a>
  <a href="http://mywebsite.com/about-us/#team">mywebsite.com/about-us/#team</a>
  <a href="http://mywebsite.com/#social">mywebsite.com/#social</a>
  <a href="http://mywebsite.com/services/#something">mywebsite.com/services/#something</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your second example, and that worked just how I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first ignore the `https://` part then find the first `/` and hope to find a `#` after it.

```js
var tests = `mywebsite.com/#find
mywebsite.com/about-us/#team
https://mywebsite.com/#social
mywebsite.com/services/#something`.split("\n");

function isMyHash(url) {
  var start = url.indexOf("://") > -1 ? url.indexOf("://") + 3 : 0;
  start = url.indexOf("/", start);
  return (url.substring(start + 1, start + 2) == '#')

}

tests.forEach(function(test) {
  console.log(test, isMyHash(test) ? "✔" : "x")
})
```